# Creating a table in Wordpress admin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two problems with WordPress.

First I am trying to create a database table with the prefix "ol" but when I add an email into my form, there is no new table created in the databaze.
Here is the code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['ol-odeslat'] ) ) {
            $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["ol-name"] );
            $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["ol-email"] );
            require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ol";
            $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'name' => $_POST['ol-name'], 'email' => $_POST['ol-email'] ) );
        }
```

Also I am trying to create a table in WordPress admin but I seem to be getting an error that there is an unexpected . (dot) on the line 171.
Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name,email FROM 'ol' ";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if ($results) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>' . $row->name; . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->email; . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first code snippet: are you actually creating the table? Does $wpdb->insert() create the table automatically if it doesn't exist?

Comment: And in your second snippet: the table name should be $wpdb->prefix . 'ol', shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

About the table creation, you have extra ; 
Between >>>;<<< in the code below

```
$sql = "SELECT name,email FROM 'ol' ";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if ($results) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>' . $row->name>>>;<<< . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->email>>>;<<< . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```